# can a .screenrc key binding contain variables?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, gnu-screen

I'm working on a customer .screenrc for Screen and I can't seem to find a way for it to support variables.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I want to press ^l, then specify a name, and that will be the logfile name.  My idea for how the .screenrc file should look was this:

```
    bindkey "^l" logfile $1
```

Any ideas on how to properly accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables.

From man screen:

> Commands may  contain references to environment variables. The syntax
>   is the shell-like "$VAR " or "${VAR}".

Answer (score 0):

Try below setting.

```
bindkey "^l" colon 'logfile '
```

You press C-a C-l, then screen input prompt is:

```
:logfile |
         ^-cursor position
```

And you continue to input logfile name.

e.g. If you would like to start logging with filename 'hoge.log' then, type this.

`C-a` `C-l` `hoge.log<ENTER>`